# Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \frac{9abc}{a+b+c} + (\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}-c)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let: $a,b,c\geq0$. Prove that:
> $$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq \frac{9abc}{a+b+c} + (\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}-c)^2$$

I tried to put $LHS-RHS$ but it is too complicated, also I tried Schur but still get nothing.

Here is my solution (not in English):
[image]

Solution 2 (from the picture): We have the following identity
\begin{align*}
 &a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - \frac{9abc}{a + b + c} - \left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b} - c\right)^2\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{(a - b)^2(ab + bc + ca)}{(a + b)^2} + \frac{a(b-c)^2 + b(c - a)^2 + c(a - b)^2}{a + b + c}.
\end{align*}
The desired inequality follows.

Comment: If I assume a = 2, b = -1 and c = 0, the left side becomes 5 while the right side becomes 25. So maybe a, b >0 as the condition???

Comment: @Macavity yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$c^2 - \left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b} - c\right)^2
= \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\left(2c - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\right).$$

It suffices to prove that
$$a^2 + b^2 + \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\left(2c - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\right) 
\ge \frac{9abc}{a + b + c}$$
or
$$1 + \frac{1}{a + b}\left(2c - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\right) 
\ge \frac{9abc}{a + b + c}\cdot \frac{1}{a^2 + b^2}.$$

Using $a^2 + b^2 \ge (a + b)^2/2$, it suffices to prove that
$$1 + \frac{1}{a + b}\left(2c - \frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\right) 
\ge \frac{9abc}{a + b + c}\cdot \frac{2}{(a + b)^2}$$
or
$$(a + b)^2 + 2c(a + b) - (a^2 + b^2) 
\ge \frac{9abc}{a + b + c}\cdot 2$$
or
$$(ab + bc + ca)(a + b + c) \ge 9abc$$
which is true using
$a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$ and $ab + bc + ca \ge 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$.

We are done.